# UIImagePickerController conflicts with AVCaptureSession video preview

Tags: ios, video, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturesession

I have a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and a `AVCaptureSession` to display a video preview on screen.

Separately, I have a `UIImagePickerController` to capture pictures (using `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`).

My problem is that when I take a picture with the `UIImagePickerController`, the `AVCaptureSession` video preview freezes.

How can prevent the video preview from freezing when I take a picture with the `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: It is hard to give an answer without having more details.

It is normal for the video preview to stop as both use the same camera device, and the image picker take ownership of it in order to take picture.

Why do you use the image picker to take image and not use the functions from AVCaptureSession directly to take picture?

Comment: post relevant codes (void)imagePickerController:pickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary

Answer (score 1):

After dismissing the video capture session try to create new view and add PBJViewcontroller over there, pass the videopath string to the viewcontroller object.

Eg:

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

UIView   *movieVW = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44, 1024, 724)];

[previewBaseView addSubview:movieVW];

_videoPlayerController = [[PBJVideoPlayerController alloc] init];

```
_videoPlayerController.delegate = self;

_videoPlayerController.view.frame = movieVW.frame;

 NSString *myString = [outputURL absoluteString];

_videoPlayerController.videoPath = myString;

 [previewBaseView addSubview:_videoPlayerController.view];
```